# Fortran: how to remove file extension from character

Tags: string, fortran, character

I have a Fortran code that asks the user for an input file name.  The code processes that file and I would like to write out another file based on the original file name.  I think if I can understand how to remove the file extension then I can just concatenate whatever I want to the end of that.

How do I strip off the file extension in a character?

character(len=256):: input_file, output_file

Original file:  AnyName.xxx

Output file: AnyName_Output.csv

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `scan` to locate the position of the last dot in the string input_file. Then you can use that position to extract the input_file with no extension and concatenate the new one.

```
character(len=256):: input_file, output_file
integer :: ppos
character(len=3)  :: new_ext="csv"

ppos = scan(trim(input_file),".", BACK= .true.)
if ( ppos > 0 ) output_file = input_file(1:ppos)//new_ext
```